# Is my function and execution correct? GCLID is not being pulled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a hidden input to capture the GCLID (Google click ID)

`<input type="hidden" id="gclid_field" name="gclid_field" value="">`

In order to capture the GCLID, I have the following Javascript below to pass the value of the function to the value of the hidden field:

```
function getParam(p) {
  var match = RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
  return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var p = '?gclid=';

document.getElementById('gclid_field').value = getParam(p);
```

I decided to test this out on my landing page and used a test auto-tagging parameter. The full url shows up in my address bar so I know my webpage allows the appending string.

http://www.website.com/?gclid=TeSter-123.

I looked in my console and saw nothing between my gclid_field xml tags.

Did I properly execute my Javascript?

Comment: You need to escape special characters since `?` has meaning in queries.

Comment: @epascarello ahhhh thank you so much!